# ora-00600 internal error code arguments: [17069],[130311952],[],[],[],[],[],[]

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I am working on developing oracle forms 6 at my pc work everything goes fine using oracle form builder and oracle database 9i

oracle form builder but when I am working at same project at my home I get the below error message

> ora-00600 internal error code arguments:
>   [17069],[130311952],[],[],[],[],[],[]

I think thats cause I am using on oracle database  11G at my home so if thats true how to solve that issue since I need oracle 11G on my pc home ??

I search and found that this message consist of six arguments which indicate the origin and attributes of the error first argument is the internal error number and the Other arguments are various numbers that may change meanings between different versions of Oracle so please I need expert help

**Note: I had noticed that everything goes right and only forms which contains 
`from dual` statement will rise this exception**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you must use SYS.DUAL from within Oracle Forms instead of plain old DUAL, as per [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600).  Quoting:

> Possible causes include:
>
> - time-outs,
> - file corruption,
> - failed data checks in memory, hardware, memory, or I/O messages,
> - incorrectly restored files
> - a SELECT FROM DUAL statement in PL/SQL within Oracle Forms (you have to use SELECT FROM SYS.DUAL instead!)